# HTML block placement

Tags: html, css

[image]

```html
<style>
   .a{
   width:500px;
   height:500px;
   background:yellow;
   border: 3px dashed black;
   }
   .b{
   width: inherit;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: -webkit-xxx-large;
   }
   .c:nth-child(odd){    
   background: orange;
   font-size: xx-large;
   }
   .c:nth-child(even){    
   background: grey;
   font-size: xx-large;
   }
</style>
<div class='a'>
   <div class='b'>
      Alert
   </div>
   <div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Hi All,
I have a case where  want to display Alert division outside the main class(class 'a').
Now Alert is present in the div with class name 'a'.
Some how i want to make Alert come before the division wit classname 'a' without using position property like top,bottom etc.
When alert comes out it's width should be of the div's width with classname 'a'
Needs to be done only using CSS.Please help
Picture one is what rendering from this code
Picture two is what i want to render

Comment: What do you expect to happen? When will the alert div move? It would be better if you can add some visual that presents what you want to happen?

Comment: @Swellar , please check now

Comment: Ok, when would you want that to happened? Upon load of the website?

Comment: @Swellar ,Yes..

Comment: i can use position prop.
But is there any property to make alert message come out of that(see border for reference)

Comment: CSS only? You can't change the HTML?

Comment: Yes,Only using CSS

Comment: Could a js solution be good for you?

Comment: No.Only CSS
I just want to know whether there is a way or not(using css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```css
    .a{
         width:500px;
         height:500px;
         background:yellow;
         border: 3px dashed black;
    }
    
    .b{
         width: inherit;
         height: 100px;
         line-height: 100px;
         background: red;
         vertical-align: middle;
         text-align: center;
         font-size: -webkit-xxx-large;
         border-left: 3px solid white;
         margin: -3px -3px 0px;
         border-bottom: 3px dashed black;
         border-right: 3px solid white;
         border-top: 3px solid white;
    }

    .c:nth-child(odd){    
         background: orange;
         font-size: xx-large;
    }

    .c:nth-child(even){    
         background: grey;
         font-size: xx-large;
    }
```

```html
<div class='a'>
   <div class='b'>
      Alert
   </div>
   <div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
      <div class=c>Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Note: This doesn't really placed the Alert division outside the main class. I just adjust the margin and border (check the CSS) to make it look like it is outside the main class. I still suggest it is better to just adjust in HTML instead or using the CSS property `position`, but as per your requirement there you go :P